# Passing props object to Vue component while keeping the properties reactive

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using Vue and Laravel.
I am trying to define a dimension object in a database, then pass the value through a prop into a component, while keeping the object properties reactive.

The database contains an object defining defining name and dimensions.  The dimensions can be simple values from the store (as item 0), or calculations on those values (as item 1).  The values in the store are set by other form input components on the page.

Database table "item", column "dimensions":

```
"{
     0:  {name: 'item0',
          size: {
                x: 'this.storeState.h.dim',
                y: 'this.storeState.w.dim',
                z: 'this.storeState.d.dim'
          }
     },
     1:  {name: 'item1',
          size: {
                x: 'this.storeState.h.dim - this.storeState.offset1.dim',
                y: 'this.storeState.w.dim + this.storeState.offset2.dim',
                z: 'this.storeState.d.dim + 100'
          }
     }
 }"
```

The laravel blade template passes props to a vue component.
show.blade.php:

```
<my-component :dimensions="{{$item->dimensions}}">
</my-component>
```

Inside my-component.Vue:

```
<script>
import { store } from "../../store.js";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            storeState: store.state
        };
    },
    props: ["dimensions"],
    methods: {

        defineItems: function() {
            return this.dimensions; 
        }
</script>
```

My problem is that the object properties arrive as strings, and are not reactive.  I'm a relative beginner and this may be obvious, but what is the right architecture to use in this case?  I could store the variable names in the object (eg. "h"), and then re-build the full location of the variable within the component, but I'm not sure how to handle the cases where the object contains a calculation with multiple variables (as in item 2).

It works when the object is defined inside the component, but I want to make the component re-useable.
Inside my-component.Vue with locally-defined object:

```
<script>
import { store } from "../../store.js";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            storeState: store.state
        };
    },
    methods: {

        defineItems: function() {
            var dimensions = {
            0: {
                name: "item0",
                size: {
                    x: this.storeState.h.dim,
                    y: this.storeState.w.dim,
                    z: this.storeState.d.dim
                }
            },
            1: {
                name: "item1",
                size: {
                    x: this.storeState.h.dim - this.storeState.offset1.dim,
                    y: this.storeState.w.dim + this.storeState.offset2.dim,
                    z: this.storeState.d.dim + 100
                }
            }
        };
        return dimensions; 
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for any pointers on how you'd approach this...

Comment: In your item example, is that output directly from the database? It appears that you're saving strings of code in your database..?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I'm just seeding the DB at the moment.  I was using the laravel model to cast to an array, but turned it off to simplify the problem in the short term.  I'm not sure how to save the "config" in the DB without also storing the code.

Comment: You would be best to store the actual values rather than references to them. And then you populate an object containing said data and simply pass that object to the front end.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  Just to check I understand...  In the DB i could store size: { x: 'height', y: 'width', z: 'depth' }, then pass that to the front end, and lookup the current value of height, width, and depth?  In that case, what would be the best way to handle for example x: 'height + offset1'.  For a bit more background, the component is three.js code that live-updates a rendering based on the sizes passed in by some form inputs.

Comment: I think we've misunderstood each other.  I'm setting up a "config" object, which needs to store the "recipe" for a rendering.  The actual values (numerical dimensions) are not known until the page is rendered, and get substituted in by Vue at that stage.  There is probably a pattern for this, but I don't know it!  I've added a three.js tag to the question just in case.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand what you're trying to achieve then. The config object you describe, will it be hard coded by you? Or user generated on the fly?

Comment: Yes, it's coded by me.  Later it will be editable through edit and update routes in the config portion of the app.  But for now it's just some config typed into the database.

Comment: Without a more thorough understanding of what you're trying to achieve its hard to offer any suitable advice I'm afraid. It's likely that theres a very simple solution, but would first need to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a fiddle to understand why this wasn't working.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ThomUK/3owxjvd7/16/)

In the end, it was a problem with my store pattern, where the store did not exist on the root Vue instance.  Here is the store on the root instance from the JSFiddle.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    store: {
      x: 500,
      y: 400,
      z: 10
    }
  }
})
```